# How to handle foreach null exception when using GetEnumerator from other class?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have two Classes **A** and **B** which implements `IEnumerable`.

**A** use GetEnumerator from **B**.
**B** is a member of Class **A**.

But the member **B** could be null, so I add null check.

The question is also stated in comments of the code example. What should be put in the other branch to stop foreach null exception?

In the following example:
`rootNode` is **B**.
The function illustrated is a function of **A**.
**B** is a member of **A**.

```cs
        public IEnumerator<BVHNode<BoundingVolumeClass>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (rootNode != null)
            {
                return rootNode.GetEnumerator();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
                //return null cause foreach null exception
                //what can be put here to stop it?
            }
        }
```

Comment: *Don't* return a null at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But if delete return null. The code wont compile.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So what should be put there?

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty<T>().GetEnumerator()` or maybe `(new T[0]).GetEnumerator()`should give you what you need. (replacing `T` with the proper type of course) though not sure if they're properly typed (writing from phone and it's rare for me to return IEnumerator, so I'm guessing)

Comment: Did you try to return empty enumerator ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.empty?view=netframework-4.7.2

=> Enumerable.Empty

Comment: @BonOeil No. I am trying. First heard of it. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexWei Check for example the [Enumerator class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140) used by List<T>. It's the *enumerator* that tells callers if there's any data to enumerate. Should class A return itself in the results for example?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. It works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No. Just the node. Thanks. Problem already solved. I guess I should check the doc more carefully next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not return `null` but use *empty collection*:

```
    public IEnumerator<BVHNode<BoundingVolumeClass>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return rootNode == null
          ? Enumerable.Empty<BVHNode<BoundingVolumeClass>>().GetEnumerator()
          : rootNode.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Comment: Also can be written as


`public IEnumerator<BVHNode<BoundingVolumeClass>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return rootNode?.GetEnumerator() ?? Enumerable.Empty<BVHNode<BoundingVolumeClass>>().GetEnumerator();
        }`